# listing all error messages in one container with jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want validation messages to be added to a container above my form in a list instead of next to the field. What I have so far works for the most part. As the user enters invalid info into fields, validation messages are added to the container in a list. The problem is that if the user goes to a field and enters valid data, the whole error list is hidden and does not come back until you click on a field which has an error. I need the error list to stay displayed and as the user fixes the fields, the corresponding messages disappear.

Here is how I set up my .validate

```
$("#myform").validate( {
    onSubmit : false,
    errorContainer : '#message',
    errorLabelContainer : '#message',
    errorElement : "li",
});
```

And then accordingly I have a UL above my form with id "error"

How do I make this work?

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or give us more of your code? There isn't really enough information in your question to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own error array using the errorList function of the plugin

```
 var summary = "";    
    jQuery.each(errorList, function() { summary += this.message + '<br />' +"\n"; });
```

With

```
.html(summary)
```

you can add the errors to an hidden error container: here is the relevant part of the code from a recent project:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
            showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                if (submitted) {
                    var summary = "";
                    jQuery.each(errorList, function() { summary += this.message + '<br />' +"\n"; });
                    var errorContainer = jQuery('#myErrorContainer');
                    errorContainer.fadeIn().html(summary);
                    submitted = false;
                }
            },
```